# File with a no-atime-updates "A" attribute still updates atime. Why?

Tags: files

```
$ stat file_1 | tail -n 4
Access:      2015-04-16 21:48:42.675095130 +0200
Modify:      2015-04-16 21:48:42.675095130 +0200
Change:      2015-04-16 21:51:31.844300132 +0200
Birth:       -
$ lsattr file_1
-------A-----e-- file_1
$ touch file_1
$ stat file_1 | tail -n 4
Access:      2015-04-16 21:53:39.597262024 +0200
Modify:      2015-04-16 21:53:39.597262024 +0200
Change:      2015-04-16 21:53:39.597262024 +0200
Birth:       -
```

Did I misunderstand the `A` attribute? (I read its description [HERE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#File_attributes))
Or does it only not-update `atime` in certain contexts?

Comment: What about if you `cat` the file? `touch` is a write; the objections to atime have always been that it gets updated on *read* (turning every read, even cached read, into a write). Updating atime alongside mtime and/or ctime is free... Not also the default on Linux now is relatime, which depending on the exact kernel version you're running may only do atime updates once per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it may not be spelled out in the documentation you linked to, 
but the intent of the `A` attribute is that the file system/operating system
should not update the access time when the file is read. 
But the `touch` program exists specifically for changing the times in inodes;
after all, its default behavior is to update the mod time
without actually modifying the file. 
So `touch` uses a more direct method to change the file's time(s). 
To test the `A` attribute, use something simple like `cat file_1`.